# Visual Studio - Git User Information

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm having some issue's with Visual Studio and Git. It keeps prompting me to set my user information, but when I try to do that it doesn't allow me to. Resulting in endless prompts, very annoying.

[image]
[image: Error message]

Any idea on how to set these credentials in Visual Studio? As I can commit/pull/etc just fine with the terminal or Visual Studio Code. Only Visual Studio seems to be having this problem.

I use Visual Studio Online as Git provider.

Comment: Check the permissions? You're inside the system32 folder which isn't renown for easy permissions.

Comment: Your comment made me think, so I tried opening it in Administrator mode. Now it did work.. Let's hope it saved it for the future too.

Comment: I think that VS is doing something wrong here because it never have to write the info in `System32` folder. It should create a file in your profile if you checked "Set in global .gitconfig` or set the config only in the repository if you unchecked it!

Answer (score 3):

you can try re installing git pluging of visual studio

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.VisualStudioToolsforGit

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Visual Studio will prompt this message as long as your git name and email are not set.
Just set them through cmd or git bash:

```
git config --global user.name "YOUR_NAME"
git config --global user.email "YOUR_EMAIL"
```